# Ticks and range in PairedBarChart

Tags: plotting

I am trying to change the ticks and range in a `PairedBarChart`because one of the ranges is much smaller than the other. How can I do this?

```
PairedBarChart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{0.2, 0.3}, {0.4, 
   0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, All},
 Ticks -> {{0, {3, "this"}, 6}, None}
 ]
```

[image]

Notice that the range doesnt permit seeing the values on the right correctly. Also, when you do `Ticks->{{0,3,6},None}` all is good, but when you want to rename one of them it goes nuts.

I don't mind rescaling the values in one of the lists, as long as I can change the ticks. Could you guys please help out?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t = 10;
ticks = {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}; 
p = PairedBarChart[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, 
                    t {{0.2, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}}, 
                    Ticks -> {ticks, Automatic}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]; 

p /. (Text[#, o : Offset[{_, _}, {_?(# > 0 &), _}], a___] :> Text[ #/t, o, a] & /@ ticks)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you could do something like this

```
data = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{0.2, 0.3}, {0.4, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}}};

b1 = BarChart[First@data, AspectRatio -> 1, BarOrigin -> Right];
b2 = BarChart[Last@data,  AspectRatio -> 1, BarOrigin -> Left];

Grid[{{b1, b2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, before knowing about `PairedBarChart`, that was indeed my approach. But I was expecting that something cleaner would exist, this because then aligning all labels (which I have not shown), among other things, would be more complicated. Still, this is a viable option if nothing else works